# How to swap different admin panel themes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there any way of swapping different admin panel themes in React? Like I have two different themes (coreui and lightreact). Is it possible to change between these themes? I have global routes and nav files which should be imported in themes instead of their own routes and nav files but every theme follows its own structure of nav objects. So is there any way to swap themes by keeping nav and routes same?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that changing themes would mean changing the entire sidebar since CoreUI sidebar styling is not only applied by sidebar nav items but also other sidebar elements. (you have other classes in lightreact in wrappers as well).

Concerning `CCreateComponent` it can be changed to standard component tree - `items` prop passed to the component contains the tree that you can use.